# How to replace QWidget in the QMainwindow

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm developing the GUI code using PyQt5.
In my code, I intend to replace from a QWidget to another QWidget in the QMainWindow.

This is my code.
I made QWidget, such as SMAP_home, SMAP_trimming, and SMAP_assembly, etc. And I made QMainWindow, Which is SMAP_Window.

```
import sys 
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class SMAP_Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        if len(args) == 0:
            self.initUI()
        else:
            self.initUI(list(args))

    def initUI(self, *args):
        self.statusBar().showMessage('')
        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('')

        newprojaction = QAction(QIcon('newfileicon.png'), 'New', self)
        loadprojaction = QAction(QIcon('loadfileicon.png'), 'Load', self)

        self.toolbar.addAction(newprojaction)
        self.toolbar.addAction(loadprojaction)

        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('smapicon.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Shotgun Metagenomics Analysis Pipeline')
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 500)

        if args == (): 
            self.setCentralWidget(SMAP_Home())
        else:
            widget = args[0][0]
            value = args[0][1:]
            if widget == 'Trimming':
                self.setCentralWidget(SMAP_Trimming(value))
                self.close()
            elif widget == 'Assembly':
                self.setCentralWidget(SMAP_Assembly(value))
            elif widget == 'Bamming':
                self.setCentralWidget(SMAP_Alignment(value))
#           elif widget == 'Binning':
#               self.setCentral Widget(SMAP_Binning(value))

        self.show()
```

I want to change among many QWidget based on SMAP_Window.
However, using my code, despite of showing new SMAP_Window with changed QWidget, conventional(existing) SMAP_window(without conventional QWidget) was not removed!!

Comment: please read [ask] and provide [mcve]